# Copying view by Drag and Drop Android

Tags: android

How can I copy a view (such as Image) from one panel to another one on Android?
I tried with:

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

                    View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;
                    container.addView(view);
                    break;
```

But, it does not work.
This is onDrag() function, my app quit by `Exception`:

```
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                // Do nothing
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                v.setBackgroundDrawable(enterShape);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                // add view 
                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;
                container.addView(view);                    
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Probabily you get an java.lang.IllegalStateException, stating that "The specified child already has a parent." What you must do is add

```
View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
owner.removeView(view);
```

when the action is DragEvent.ACTION_DROP.

Comment: But I want to copy view by drag and drop. If I add this code, it just move view

Comment: Then, you need to copy the Image from the ImageView and create a new ImageView which you will add to the container with `Drawable copyImage = copyView.getDrawable();ImageView image = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);image.setImageDrawable(copyImage);`. Also, make sure that you don't make the view invisible when you call  `v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);`.

Comment: thanks u, could you answer my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907703/create-edittext-by-drag-drop-android-issue